# How to correct status 400 with event.path with AWS Lambda & API Gateway?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I want to use the AWS Lambda function below that is integrated with API Gateway to call 2 different routes. Please review the code below for that implementation:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    if (event.path === '/countries') {
      const countriesResponse = await axios.get('https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/states');

      const countryNames = countriesResponse.data.data.map(country => country.name);

      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(countryNames),
      };
      
    } else if (event.path === '/states') {
      const { country } = JSON.parse(event.body);

      const statesResponse = await axios.post('https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/states', { country });

      const stateNames = statesResponse.data.data.states.map(state => state.name);

      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(stateNames),
      };
    } else {
      console.log(event.path);
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Invalid endpoint' })
      };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Internal Server Error' })
    };
  }
};
```

I want to be able to call GET on `/countries` to return all countries returned by the API I'm calling. I also want to be able to call POST on `/states` to return all states for a provided country. To be specific, I would like to be able to make the following API call:

```
POST ENDPOINT: `https://api-id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/develop/states`

BODY: {"country":"Canada"}
```

Currently, when I do this, I'm getting:

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "body": "{\"message\":\"Invalid endpoint\"}"
}
```

That tells me that for some reason the endpoint is not being hit properly. Why is that? I've confirmed the endpoint `\states` and `\countries` are in the API Gateway. They also seem to be matching in the API call and the code. But perhaps there's something I'm missing and I'm not using `event.path` correctly.

ADDITIONAL DETAIL BASED ON COMMENT BELOW:

I have logged the event and found it to be the following object:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "routeKey": "POST /states",
    "rawPath": "/develop/states",
    "rawQueryString": "",
    "headers": {
        "accept": "*/*",
        "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "content-length": "26",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "host": "cc1sxgjhi4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        "postman-token": "848e4596-d42d-4606-b84e-67ce27f05dfa",
        "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.35.0",
        "x-amzn-trace-id": "Root=1-659800b6-5a35109603b2112664c29481",
        "x-forwarded-for": "142.112.6.191",
        "x-forwarded-port": "443",
        "x-forwarded-proto": "https"
    },
    "requestContext": {
        "accountId": "624448452992",
        "apiId": "cc1sxgjhi4",
        "domainName": "cc1sxgjhi4.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        "domainPrefix": "cc1sxgjhi4",
        "http": {
            "method": "POST",
            "path": "/develop/states",
            "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
            "sourceIp": "142.112.6.191",
            "userAgent": "PostmanRuntime/7.35.0"
        },
        "requestId": "REUMkjYdIAMEVmQ=",
        "routeKey": "POST /states",
        "stage": "develop",
        "time": "05/Jan/2024:13:14:30 +0000",
        "timeEpoch": 1704460470586
    },
    "body": "{\n  \"country\": \"Canada\"\n}\n",
    "isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

`develop` is the stage that I created on AWS and deployed the API Gateway on. I have tried the POST to `https://api-id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/develop/states`, `https://api-id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/states` and GET to `https://api-id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/develop/countries`, `https://api-id.execute-api.region.amazonaws.com/countries`

Answer (score 0):

Try to log the event object and see what is coming in it (Also add it in the question so that we can check further). It might probably have `/develop/states` instead of `/states`. If `develop` is something like a prefix and you don't want to use it then you can try using `event.resourcePath` instead.

Comment: I added comments the post above. I logged the event object. Both the `develop/states` and `/states` endpoints are resulting in status 400. This was helpful to debug and resolve the issue. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the `event.path`. I should have been calling an if on `event.rawPath` instead. Below is the full corrected code.

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    console.log('EVENT');
    console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    if (event.rawPath === '/countries') {
      const countriesResponse = await axios.get('https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/states');

      const countryNames = countriesResponse.data.data.map(country => country.name);

      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(countryNames),
      };
      
    } else if (event.rawPath === '/states') {
      const { country } = JSON.parse(event.body);

      const statesResponse = await axios.post('https://countriesnow.space/api/v0.1/countries/states', { country });
      console.log(statesResponse);
      const stateNames = statesResponse.data.data.states.map(state => state.name);

      return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(stateNames),
      };
    } else {
      return {
        statusCode: 400,
        body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Invalid endpoint' })
      };
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      body: JSON.stringify({ message: 'Internal Server Error' })
    };
  }
};
```